# How to implement out of WTL header file?

Tags: c++, wtl

WTL is template library, so i have to implement it in template library header file.

I want to implement my logic in `.cpp` file otherwise,  i will have to code a huge header file.

for example, in MainFrm.h

```
// ...
// MainFrm.h
class CMainFrame : 
    public CFrameWindowImpl<CMainFrame>, 
    public CUpdateUI<CMainFrame>,
    public CMessageFilter, public CIdleHandler
{
  //...
  void function1()
  {
    //...
  }

  void function2()
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

I want to have `function1()` and `function2()` in `myfunction.cpp`, how to do it?

Please guide.

EDIT:

Solved! thanks to Jan S. i had include myfunction.cpp into WTL project and add some lines:

MainFrm.h:

```
// ...
// MainFrm.h
#if 1
#include <atlframe.h>
#include <atlsplit.h>
#include <atlctrls.h>
#include <atlctrlw.h>
#include <atlctrlx.h>
#include "sampleView.h"
#include "resource.h"
#endif

// MainFrm.h
class CMainFrame : 
    public CFrameWindowImpl<CMainFrame>, 
    public CUpdateUI<CMainFrame>,
    public CMessageFilter, public CIdleHandler
{
  //...
  void functionx();
  //...
};
```

myfunction.cpp:

```
// myfunction.cpp
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "MainFrm.h"
void CMainFrame::functionx()
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Difference between a c++ definition and declaration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Comment: You may be thinking of a template before it is explicitly instantiated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your header put the declaration

```
// MainFrm.h
class CMainFrame : 
    public CFrameWindowImpl<CMainFrame>, 
    public CUpdateUI<CMainFrame>,
    public CMessageFilter, public CIdleHandler
{
  //...
  void functionx();
  //...
};
```

In your .cpp file put the definition

```
#include MainFrm.h

void CMainFrame::functionx()  
{  
    // more code  
}
```

**The compiler errors**

You seem to be missing WTL header includes

```
#include <atlframe.h>
#include <atlsplit.h>
```

---

Off topic but, in your header make sure you have

```
#pragma once
```

or

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_HEADER_NAME
#define UNIQUE_HEADER_NAME
//header code
#endif
```

This will stop duplicate declarations.

Comment: The #ifndef should be at the beginning and the #endif at the end of the header file